# Passing data with ajax POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, reactjs

```
submit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/data',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ Markers: 'heleeo' }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: () => {
            console.log('wrong');
        }
    });

}
```

when trying to access it with my node.js server it throws an error saying markers is undefined

```
apiRoutes.post('/data', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.Markers);
});
```

Comment: what console.log(req.body) gives

Comment: @owaishanif786 undefined

Comment: try without contentType: "application/json",

Comment: try passing in { Markers: 'heleeo' } directly, without stringifying.  jQuery.ajax should automatically convert it to a query string for you.

Comment: @owaishanif786 tried both of those and still returning undefined

Comment: what is the return status?

Comment: you are not posting it right. for me its working. see in network tab and what is status of request also what is data being send and response you are getting preview it.

Comment: @owaishanif786 nope everything is going fine in the network part, idk why the json is not getting passed thro tho. weird

Comment: can you share further details like this http://imgur.com/U9TxLcM

Comment: Try change `data: JSON.stringify({ Markers: 'heleeo' }),` to `data: { Markers: 'heleeo' },` or do `JSON.parse(req.body).Markers`